# Cannot set mainTexture of a Material in Unity Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, texture2d

I'm trying to set the mainTexture of a Material but with no success. Here is the piece of code I'm using :

```
//Material
skinData.m_Diffuse = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/TransparentVertexCol"));
UnityEngine.Object o;
node = root.GetChild("Diffuse");
if( node != null )
{
    string name = node.value;
    o = Resources.Load<Texture2D>(name);
    skinData.m_Diffuse.mainTexture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>(name);
}
```

I added the Object o for debug purpose. When I trace the code I have o set to a Texture2D and my skinData.m_Diffuse.mainTexture is null. It worked a couple of weeks ago. In the mean time I updated Unity to version 5.3 and added a lot of other scripts that should not impact directly this.

I guess there must be a reason why i can set a "free" var like o and not the mainTexutre but there is no message, no exception, nothing so if anyone has any idea...

Comment: Did you try with `skinData.m_Diffuse.SetTexture ("_MainTex", Resources.Load<Texture2D>(name));` Dubble check what is the name of the texture in the shader.

Comment: you're right, looks like it has to do with the shader, when I use "Unlit/Texture" it's set as it should. The name of the texture in the shader is _MainTex, but I may have another problem. Do you know if there has been some breaking changes in shaders between 5.1 and 5.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was linked to the shadercompiler.exe that did not work properly. I did not have a specific message at the time and then, when I tried to edit my shader to see what could be wrong I started to have another problem that you can see here [Failed to get socket connection from UnityShaderCompiler.exe shader compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882029/failed-to-get-socket-connection-from-unityshadercompiler-exe-shader-compiler). I the end, all was fine in the code.
All was solved by the patch 5.3.1p3