# Failed to get socket connection from UnityShaderCompiler.exe shader compiler

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In Unity each time I try to change/set a shader to a material (in code or in the editor) Unity hangs for a while and logs "Failed to get socket connection from UnityShaderCompiler.exe shader compiler!" in the console.

I killed Unity, rebooted the PC, deactivated the firewall, nothing seems to change anything. I googled the error message but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, maybe that will be stupid as I dont see really chance for it, but try to disable antivirus if you have one :) Maybe somehow it interfers the socet process to process comunication between Unity3D and UnityShaderCompiler.exe.

Comment: Nope, doesn't change a thing :/

Comment: What version of Unity, the newest one? Is it maybe a problem with privileges (start everything as admin e.g.)? `Socket Connection` definetly refers to IPC (Inter Process Communication) here, so if that fails it may even be a Unity bug.

Comment: Yes it's the latest version (5.3.1f1) and starting it as admin doesn't change anything.

Comment: It is not a latest version. Install 5.3.1p3 (in patches)

Comment: Ha ok I didn't know about patches, I always looked in the help menu -> "Check for update". I Installed the patch and it corrected the problem. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific issue was resolved by Jerry's comment to update to Unity 5.3.1p3. The issue was a Unity bug in an older version.

(For those who are running into this error message while working with Jenkins, there is a more recent and [relevant Stack Exchange post for this error message when running a Jenkins build](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/150581/115296) using Unity 2017.1)

Comment: (Also, see [meta post on "What should be done with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117251/388203))